# Apps: TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequet returns null

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I created a new Project for Sharepoint 2013 Apps in the Visual Studio 12. I choosed autohosted and added the link to my SP Web Home Site. I also added:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read" />
```

in the AppManifest.

So why is the method `TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequet` in the Default.aspx.cs always returning null?

Comment: Im facing the same issue. However i have narrowed down the issue. If i open the page in modal dialog than GetContextTokenFromRequet returns always null. otherwise it is fine. The reason is request.Form["SPAppToken"] is null. Can somebody tell me the solution for this

Comment: are you trying for custom STS  ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your sharepoint app is secure or not.
I had same problem. fixed by updating start-up page from http:// to https:// in AppManifest.xml

<StartPage>https://sampledemonamexx.azurewebsites.net/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to deploy your app to Office 365 or an on-premises environment? If you are on-premises, you cannot use an Autohosted app. Instead, you will need to:

- Configure a public and private test certificate for your environment (if you don't have Azure ACS configured)
- Configure app isolation
- Run some PowerShell cmdlets
- (Optionally) Turn off the HTTPS requirement for OAuth in your dev environment
- Create a new provider-hosted app in Visual Studio, configured to use a certificate for authentication

These steps are spelled out in much greater detail in the second half of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179901.aspx). I have verified that they work with Preview 2 of the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012, available for download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=GetInstallerRedirect&appid=OfficeToolsForVS2012GA). (I mention this because Preview 2 of the Office Dev Tools was released after you posted this question.)